# 画像を挿入できない。

Tags: php

PHPでECサイトを作成しています。
商品登録時に画像を挿入する機能を作りたいのですが、

```
$img_path = '../file/';
       
        $image = file_get_contents( $img_path );
       
        $new_img = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['new_img']['tmp_name'], '../file/' . $image);
```

上記のコードだと
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以下のようなエラーが発生し、画像を挿入することが出来ません。
お手数をおかけしますがご教授お願い致します。

ソースコード
functions.php

```
<?php
require_once('../../include/conf/const.php');

function get_db_connect() {
 
if (!$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWD, DB_NAME)) {
        die('error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    mysqli_set_charset($link, DB_CHARACTER_SET);
    return $link;
}

function close_db_connect($link) {

    mysqli_close($link);
}

function insert_item($link) {
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
    return;
}
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'insert') {
        
        if (isset($_POST['name']) === TRUE) {
            
            $new_name = $_POST['name'];
        }
        
        if (isset($_POST['price']) === TRUE) {
        
            $new_price = $_POST['price'];
            
        }
        
        if (isset($_POST['stock']) === TRUE) {
            
            $new_stock = $_POST['stock'];
        }
        
        $img_path = '../file/';
       
        $image = file_get_contents( $img_path );
       
        $new_img = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['new_img']['tmp_name'], '../file/' . $image);
        
        if (isset($_POST['status']) === TRUE) {
        if ((int) $_POST['status'] === 0 || (int) $_POST['status'] === 1) {
             
             $new_status = (int) $_POST['status'];
        }
            
        }
        
            $new_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO item_tb(name, price, stock, img, status, created_date, updated_date) VALUES(\''.$new_name.'\',\''.$new_price.'\',\''.$new_stock.'\',\''.$new_img.'\',\''.$new_status.'\',\''.$new_time.'\',\''.$new_time.'\')';

            if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {

                $drink_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = 'DBエラーが発生しました。';
                return $err_msg;
                
                
            }
                
            }
    }


        
function update_item($link) {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'update') {
        if (isset($_POST['item_id']) === TRUE) {
            (int)$item_id = (int)$_POST['item_id'];
        }
        
        if (isset($_POST['stock']) === TRUE) {
                (int)$update_stock = (int)($_POST['stock']);

                $sql = 'UPDATE item_tb SET stock = ' . $update_stock. ' Where id =' . $item_id;
                if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {
                } else {
                   $err_msg[] = 'DBエラーが発生しました。';
                   return $err_msg;
                }
                }
        }
}





function change_item($link) {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'change') {
         if (isset($_POST['item_id']) === TRUE) {
            
            (int)$item_id = (int)$_POST['item_id'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['change_status']) === TRUE) {
            if ((int) $_POST['change_status'] === 0 || (int) $_POST['change_status'] === 1) {
                $change_status = (int) $_POST['change_status'];
                $sql = 'UPDATE item_tb SET status = ' . $change_status. ' Where id =' . $item_id;

                if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {
                    
                } else {
                    $err_msg[] = 'ステータスの変更に失敗しました';
                }
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = 'ステータスは公開か非公開を選択してください';
                return $err_msg;
            }
        }
    }
    
}

function delete_item($link) {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'delete') {
        
         if (isset($_POST['item_id']) === TRUE) {
             
            (int)$item_id = (int)$_POST['item_id'];
            
        }
        if (isset($_POST['delete']) === TRUE) {
                $sql = 'DELETE FROM item_tb Where id =' . $item_id;

                if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {
                    
                } else {
                    $err_msg[] = '削除に失敗しました';
                return $err_msg;
            }
        }
    }
    
}


function do_sql($link) {
    $sql = 'SELECT item_tb.id, item_tb.name, item_tb.price, item_tb.stock, item_tb.img, item_tb.status
    FROM item_tb';
    $data = [];
    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    } else {
        $err_msg[] = 'データの抽出に失敗しました';
    }
    return $data;
}

function complete_check_insert($link) {
    $complete_msg[] = '追加登録完了!';
    return $complete_msg;
}

function complete_check_update($link) {
    $complete_msg[] = '在庫数更新完了!';
    return $complete_msg;
}

function complete_check_change($link) {
    $complete_msg[] = 'ステータス変更完了!';
    return $complete_msg;
}

function complete_check_delete($link) {
    $complete_msg[] = '削除完了!';
    return $complete_msg;
}

function validation_check($link) {
   $err_msg = [];
   if (!isset($_POST['name']) || (isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] === ""))  {
     $err_msg[] = '商品名を入力してください。';
    }
    
    if (!isset($_POST['price']) || (isset($_POST['price']) && $_POST['price'] === "")) {
     $err_msg[] = '値段を入力してください';
    } else if(preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/',($_POST['price'])) !== 1) {
     $err_msg[] = '値段は0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
    }
    
    if (!isset($_POST['stock']) || (isset($_POST['stock']) && $_POST['stock'] === "")) {
     $err_msg[] = '在庫を入力してください';
    } else if(preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/',($_POST['stock'])) !== 1) {
     $err_msg[] = '在庫は0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
    }
    
    if (!empty($_POST["status"])) {
    if ((int) $_POST['status'] === 2) {
     $err_msg[] = 'ステータスは公開か非公開を選択してください'; 
    }
    }
return $err_msg;
}
    


function get_post_data($key) {
   $str = '';
   if (isset($_POST[$key]) === TRUE) {
       $str = $_POST[$key];
   }
   return $str;
}
```

tool.php

```
<?php
$data = [];
require_once('../../include/conf/const.php');
require_once('../../include/model/functions.php');
$link = get_db_connect();
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $err_msg = validation_check($link);
     if ($err_msg == [])   {
        $data = insert_item($link);
        $complete_msg = complete_check_insert($link);
    }
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
        $data = update_item($link);
        $complete_msg = complete_check_update($link);
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST['change'])) {
        $data = change_item($link);
        $complete_msg = complete_check_change($link);
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        $data = delete_item($link);
        $complete_msg = complete_check_delete($link);
    }
    
    if (count($err_msg) !== 0)  {
        foreach ($err_msg as $err) { ?>
            <p><?php print $err; ?></p> 
    <?php }
    }
    
    if (count($complete_msg) !== 0)  {
        foreach ((array)$complete_msg as $comp) { ?>
            <p><?php print $comp; ?></p> 
    <?php }
    }
$data = do_sql($link);
require_once('../../include/view/tool2.php');

close_db_connect($link);
```

tool2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php require_once('../../htdocs/mvc/tool.php');?>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ECサイト</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>ECサイト</h1>
    <a href='../../mvc/usertool.php'>ユーザ管理ページ</a>

    <section>
        <h2>新規商品追加</h2>

        <form action="tool.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>名前: <input type="text" name="name" size="30" /></label><br>
            <label>値段: <input type="text" name="price" size="30" /></label><br>
            <label>個数: <input type="text" name="stock" size="30" /></label><br>
            <p></p>
            <input type="file" name="new_img" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif" /><br>
            <select name="status"><br>
                <option value="0">非公開</option>
                <option value="1">公開</option>
                <option value="2">入力チェック用</option>
            </select><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="insert">
            <input type="submit" name="add" value="■□■□商品追加■□■□" />
        </form>

    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>商品情報変更</h2>
        <table>
            <caption>商品一覧</caption>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>商品名</th>
                    <th>価格</th>
                    <th>在庫数</th>
                    <th>ステータス</th>
                </tr>
                <?php 
                if (empty($data) !== TRUE) {
                    foreach ((array)$data as $list) {
                        if ((int) $list['status'] === 0) { ?>
                            <tr class="status_0">
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <? php print htmlspecialchars($list,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?>
                            <td class="d_name"><?php print $list['name']; ?></td>
                            <td class="d_price"><?php print $list['price']; ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <form method="post">
                                    <input type="text" class="input_text_width text_align_right" name="update_stock" value="<?php echo $list['stock']; ?>">個
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="submit" name="update" value="変更">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="update">
                            </td>
                            
                            
                            <?php if ((int) $list['status'] === 0) { ?>
                                <td class="d_status">
                                    <form method="post">
                                        <input type="submit" name="change" value="非公開 → 公開">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="change_status" value="1">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="change">
                                        <input name="item_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $list['id']; ?>">
                                         </form>
                                          </td>
                                    <td class="d_delete">
                                    <form method="post">
                                    <input name="item_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $list['id']; ?> ">
                                    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="削除">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="delete">
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <td class="d_status">
                                <form method="post">
                                    <input type="submit"  name="change" value="公開 → 非公開">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="change_status" value="0">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="change">
                                    <input name="item_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $list['id']; ?> ">
                                    </form>
                                     </td>
                                    <td class="d_delete">
                                    <form method="post">
                                    <input name="item_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $list['id']; ?> ">
                                    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="削除">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="delete">
                                    </form>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                <?php }
                        }
                    } ?>
                                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

const.php

```
<?php
$err_msg = [];
$complete_msg = [];
$data = [];
$user = "";
$password = 0;
$login_err_flag = TRUE;

define('DB_HOST',   ''); // データベースのホスト名又はIPアドレス
define('DB_USER',   '');  // MySQLのユーザ名
define('DB_PASSWD', '');    // MySQLのパスワード
define('DB_NAME',   '');    // データベース名

define('HTML_CHARACTER_SET', 'UTF-8');  // HTML文字エンコーディング
define('DB_CHARACTER_SET',   'UTF8');   // DB文字エンコーディング

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
```

Answer (score 0):

`move_uploaded_file` の2番目の引数 (移動先) を、`/` から始まる **絶対パス** で指定してみてください。

**例:**

```php
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['new_img']['tmp_name'], '/var/www/files/' . $image);
```

Comment: 上手くいきませんでした。そもそもtmp_nameに何を入れればいいかわかりません。